# treating a value returned from a promise with es6 syntax [edited]

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make my code more easier to read and more efficient, I am in an algorithmic problem here where I am trying to implement something like this (see the code).
I am trying to do some stuff according to the level argument value, How can I implement this stuff without "repeating my self" mean without repeating the same code which should be soon placed inside [X]

```js
if(DOMHA === 'one'){
    JSON.then(json => {
        console.log("STARTED FETCHING level 1");
        UI.fetch(level1, json.level.one);
        return 'one';
    })
}
else if(DOMHA === 'two'){
        JSON.then(json => {
            console.log("STARTED FETCHING level 2");
            UI.fetch(level2, json.level.two);
            return 'two';
        })

}
.then(level => {
// [X] do anything according to level value
});
```

Comment: Why not having the code in a function? since your main concern is not repeating yourself this is the first thing to do, something else to mention here is to structure your data in away allow to have a flexible implementation, but since you didn't include your implementation of the whole no one can help in that.

Answer (score 0):

I would humbly do something like this:

```
(async () => {
    const DOMHA = 'one'; // or 'two'
    const level = DOMHA == 'one' ? level1 : level2;
    const doTheThing = async (level, DOMHA) => {
        const json = await JSON;
        console.log(`STARTED FETCHING level ${DOMHA}`);
        const theThing = await UI.fetch(level, json.level[DOMHA]);
        return theThing;
    };

    if (DOMHA !== 'one' && DOMA !== 'two') return console.error('Wrong DOMHA');
    const something = await doTheThing(level, DOMHA);
    // do anything then
})();
```

I don't have so much of your program, the problem I see is DOMHA only accept 'one' or 'two', if later I want to change that I will need extra time to work again this code.

Answer (score 0):

If level is depend on DOMHA value you can first create map

```js
var levelMap={
  "one":level1,
  "two":level2
}
```

and then create a method with just having a single argument DOMHA, and call it where you need

```js
function getValue(DOMHA){
  JSON.then(json => {
    UI.fetch(levelMap[DOMHA], json.level[DOMHA]);
    return DOMHA;
  })
}
```

The solution I write according to see your code, but if I don't understood properly please give a comment mentioning what you need